# varchar and int syntax in sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER leave_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON leaveapplication
 FOR EACH ROW
 IF employeemaster.empcode='".$empcode."' THEN
 UPDATE employeemaster SET '".$leave_type=$leave_type."'-$numberofleave //I am facing problem here
 END IF;
```

Please help me correcting it syntactically GIVEN `$leave_type` is `varchar` and `$numberofleave` is `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need save the field name in a different var

```
UPDATE employeemaster SET '".$fieldName."=".$leave_type."'-$numberofleave
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused with what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create a trigger that will automatically do the following query?

```
UPDATE 
    employeemaster 
        SET leave_type=leave_type-".$numberofleave." 
        where empcode='".$empcode."'
```

Then I think you want to write the trigger as this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER leave_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON leaveapplication
    FOR EACH ROW
        UPDATE employeemaster SET leave_type=leave_type-NEW.numberofleave where empCode=NEW.empCode
    END;
```

In the trigger, you don't want to use any variables from PHP with specifics. You want to insert the data into one table (leaveApplication) and then have the trigger use the data in that table to update the *employeemaster*. If you hardcode the data in the trigger, you will either need to create a trigger for every row of data in the *employeemaster* or the trigger won't work as expected.

Comment: @Aragorn Can you give this a whirl? I am guessing at some column names though, so you might want to adapt to your actual names.